# Как из предложения удалить гласные на чистом JS?

Tags: javascript

Даны такие строчки:

```
("This website is for losers LOL!"),
 ( "Ths wbst s fr lsrs LL!")
```

Надо удалить все гласные из предложений, не используя никаких фрэймворков, кроме чистого `JS`. Как этого добиться?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну или при помощи методов массива:

```
let str = 'This website is for losers LOL!';
const res = str.split('').filter(letter => !['a','e','i','o','u','y'].includes(letter.toLowerCase())).join('');
console.log(res);
```